# how to show related product may customer interesting on shopping website

Tags: php, web, webserver, theory

i'm customer, yesterday i go amazon look some book on website but don't buy it.
[this it book i look](http://www.uppic.org/image-CDFE_57843858.jpg)

and today i going in amazon again. and i see related item book page.[related book](http://www.uppic.org/image-28CB_57843858.jpg)

how to do like this, without problem server overload if people coming to website 10000 people in same time.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of "persistent cookies", to remember your user's preference at client side.

> A persistent cookie, is a file that is stored on a user's hard drive.
>   The cookie would remain on the hard drive until it reaches its
>   expiration date. At this point the browser would purge the cookie from
>   the hard drive.

For more information about persistent cookies, refer this link or google it.
http://www.allaboutcookies.org/cookies/persistent-cookies-used-for.html

Listing the relevant products based on their previous history would attract your customers. At end of the day this will increase your sales.

Comment: thanks for sharing, but if i do this, every time that user coming it must be render new webpage without cache right? if i have 10000 people coming in my website in same time server must be down.

Comment: @Narongsak Keawmanee; At server side, you can enable the cache to handle your website load. (Note: Please don't change your question; current question is totally different from your previous question.)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the best way is to keep the flag in your database for wishlist etc. cookies wont work if the same user login from another pc